# Is there a reverse function of lookat for glMatrix?

Tags: webgl

I am using the glMatrix to code Webgl and want to get the eye position, focal point and up direction from the existing projection and view matrix (kinda like the reverse of lookat function). Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

I didn't implement one, no. I'm not even sure that you could decompose it into the original vectors, for that matter. The lookAt point could be anywhere along a ray from the origin, and how would you determine what the appropriate up vector was? I'm thinking this is a one-way algorithm (just too lazy to prove it!)

Beyond that, however, I question wether you would want to do this even if there was a method for it. I'll be willing to bet that it's almost always more beneficial to track the values you're using and manipulate them rather than to try and pull them back and forth from matrix to vectors and back.

Comment: No it's possible. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74876243/1186624) in other question.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes** and **No**: Yes you can invert the model view transformation and no you will not get exactly all three vectors the same.

The model view transformation of `lookAt` is very similar to the `connectTo` operation as used in CSG models. It is mounting your scene in front of your camera. This is done by translation and three axis rotations. The `eye` point is translated to `(0,0,0)` and all further rotation is done around it. You can easily derive the eye point by transforming `(0,0,0)` with the inverse matrix.

But the center point is just used for adjusting the axis of view along the `-Z` axis. In openGL the eye is facing to `-Z`. The distance between center and eye is lost. So you can easy get a center point along your axis of view if you define the distance yourself. Let's say we want a distance of `d`. Then we just need to transform `(0,0,-d)` with the inverse matrix and we get a valid center point, but not exactly the same. The center point is defining only two rotation angles, the camera pan and tilt.

Even more worse is the reconstruction of the up vector. It is only used for the roll angle of the camera and thus only for one scalar value. Thus for the inverse transformation you can not only choose any positive value along the Y axis, you could choose any point in the YZ plane with a positive Y value. To get a up vector perfectly normal to the viewing axis and of size 1 we just transform `(0,1,0)` with the inverse matrix. Remember to transform as vector this time (not as point).

Now we have eye, center and up reconstructed in a way to get exactly the same result of `lookAt` next time. But since this matrix contains only 6 values of information (translation,pan,tilt,roll) we had to choose 3 values that were lost (distance center to eye, size and angle of up vector in YZ plane of camera).

The model view matrix can of course do other transformation (any affine) but the lookAt function is using this matrix only for translation and rotation. It is adjusting the scene in front of the camera without distorting it.

Comment: No it's possible. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74876243/1186624) in other question.

Comment: I'm assuming a perspective projection is used because the OP said a focal point.