# Getting camera calibration (fx, fy, cx, cy) from projection matrix

Tags: opengl, matrix, graphics, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I understand from this presentation: http://www.terathon.com/gdc07_lengyel.pdf
[image]

The focal length (fx) is the first value (e) in all OpenGL projection 4x4 matrices.

How would we get the values of principal point (cx, cy) from this projection matrix? Is it possible? I also know the view matrices.

Comment: The X/Y sub-matrix is symmetrical which means the principal point is the center of the image.

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74876243/1186624) on other question.

Answer (score 0):

The matrix in question describes a central perspective projection. It would seem the principal point of that would have to be (0, 0)…

Comment: Is the 0,0 a specific value in the perspective projection matrix? If so, which row and column is it?

Comment: @RJK depends on the matrix type ... there are more projection matrices out there ... how is this question different from your other one [Is it possible to get principal point from a projection matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55248431/2521214)